# How to get iterator in a Object Key Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code where I am iterating through a map. I want to get some type of iterator for each map entry I go through. Here is my code:

```
{
  Object.keys(element.auditdiff).map(dataType => {
    if (dataType !== "Lid" && dataType !== "Datacenter" && dataType !== "Id")
      return Object.keys(element.auditdiff[dataType]).map(data => {
        //can I somehow make this include an iterator???
        return (
          <Table.Row key={data}>
            <Table.Cell>
              <Button
                content="Update Row"
                color="green"
                disabled={updated.indexOf(key) > -1}
                onClick={() => {
                  this.handleUpdate(key);
                }} //I want to send the update for each iterator
              />
            </Table.Cell>
          </Table.Row>
        );
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *include an iterator*?

Comment: What would be the iterator used for?

Comment: It would be an index so I can index into each table row's button to disable it. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Within your map function you can pass and index to check against.

I would suggest using the index as your key.

Like so:

```
{Object.keys(element.auditdiff).map((dataType, index) => {
    return (
        <Table.Row key={index}></Table.Row>
    )
})}
```